# How I can save my own trained word embedding model in the same format of Google word2vec and Glove saved using Keras?

Tags: keras, model, save

I trained my own word embedding model on my specific data set, I want to save the model for later classification of unknown data set. However, I tried to save model using different format such as (.txt,.mdl,.bin). but when I open the file the data seems to have weird characters. How I could save my model in the same format of Glove and word2vec, the word followed by its vector..?

```
                ��������غe     ��������        `              �       �                                     TREE   ����������������                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      HEAP    X       0       �              model_weights   optimizer_weights              (                                     �       �       H        keras_version                                          @        backend                          
              H     
   model_config                             d                  `�a     h                         �      �       TREE   ����������������        p                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             HEAP    X       0       �              embedding_1     flatten_1       dense_1        (                                     `      �       `        layer_names                             embedding_1flatten_1  dense_1            @        backend                          
                   H      h                                               GCOL                        2.2.5
```

this is the code I run from https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-word-embedding-layers-deep-learning-keras/#comment-507619:

```
from numpy import array
from keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
# define documents
docs = ['Well done!',
        'Good work',
        'Great effort',
        'nice work',
        'Excellent!',
        'Weak',
        'Poor effort!',
        'not good',
        'poor work',
        'Could have done better.']
# define class labels
labels = array([1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0])
# integer encode the documents
vocab_size = 50
encoded_docs = [one_hot(d, vocab_size) for d in docs]
print(encoded_docs)
# pad documents to a max length of 4 words
max_length = 4
padded_docs = pad_sequences(encoded_docs, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')
print(padded_docs)
# define the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 8, input_length=max_length))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
# compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
# summarize the model
print(model.summary())
# fit the model
model.fit(padded_docs, labels, epochs=50, verbose=0)
# evaluate the model
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(padded_docs, labels, verbose=0)
print('Accuracy: %f' % (accuracy*100))
```

Answer (score 0):

simply I used this by Gensim

```
model.wv.save_word2vec_format('myModel.txt', binary=False)
```

It gives me the word followed by its vector